# prevent mouseleave function from interrupting mousenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I use jQuery mousenter/mousleave to execute functions with my logo. I also use Animate.css.

```
$(".logo-1").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
        $(".logo-2").css("display", "inline-block");
        $("#facebook").css("visibility", "visible").css("-webkit-animation-duration", "0.1s").addClass("animated fadeInDown").one("animationend oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd",
        function() {
          $("#linked").css("visibility", "visible").css("-webkit-animation-duration", "0.1s").addClass("animated fadeInDown").one("animationend oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd",
          function() {
            $("#instagram").css("visibility", "visible").css("-webkit-animation-duration", "0.1s").addClass("animated fadeInDown").one("animationend oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd",
            function() {
              $("#github").css("visibility", "visible").css("-webkit-animation-duration", "0.1s").addClass("animated fadeInDown").one("animationend oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd",
              function() {
                $("#facebook, #linked, #instagram, #github").removeClass("animated fadeInDown")
              });
                    });
                  });
                });
              });

$(".logo-social").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#github").addClass("animated fadeOutUp").one("animationend oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd",
          function() {
            $("#instagram").addClass("animated fadeOutUp").one("animationend oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd",
              function() {
                $("#linked").addClass("animated fadeOutUp").one("animationend oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd",
                  function() {
                    $("#facebook").addClass("animated fadeOutUp").one("animationend oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd",
                      function() {
                        $("#facebook, #linked, #instagram, #github").removeClass("animated fadeOutUp").css("visibility", "hidden");
                        $(".logo-2").css("display", "none");
                        $(".logo-1").css("display", "inline-block");
                      });
                  });
                });
            });
          });
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="logo-social">
          <div class="dg">
            <img src="img/logo-1.png" class="logo-1" alt="logo">
            <img src="img/logo-2.png" class="logo-2" alt="logo">
          </div>
          <div class="wrapper">
           <div class="media-links-1">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gorniczy" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook-logo-dark.png" id="facebook" alt="Facebook logo"></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/denis-gornichar-56b3b564/" target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin-sign-dark.png" id="linked" alt="LinkedIn logo"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gorniczy/" target="_blank"><img src="img/instagram-symbol-dark.png" id="instagram" alt="Instagram logo"></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/gorniczy" target="_blank"><img src="img/github-sign-dark.png" id="github" alt="Github logo"></a>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

Everithing works fine when I wait until mouseenter function finishes before moving the cursor elsewhere. But if I move the cursor before the first function is finished, it's interrupted by the second one which leads to bugs.

I want my mouseleave function to start executing only after the mousenter function is finished no matter when I move the cursor elsewhere.

Comment: Post the animation code.... It's on the animation code you need help. The event handlers just are triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a stack of 4~5 callbacks for your animations.
So I understand why you wish to work on "trigger prevention".

Here is a way using "flags". One for each "disabled" state... And one to always now if the mouse is in or out the logo.

Then, using timeouts and those flags, you can prevent the animation execution... While making sure to do the "out" animation if the mouse is out after the "in" is over.

```
var disableIn = false,
    disableOut = false,
    animationDelayIn = 600,     // Set those two delays based on your animation times
    animationDelayOutIn = 600,
    currentlyIn = false;

$(".logo").mouseenter(function(){

  currentlyIn = true;

  if(!disableIn){
    //otherAnimation
  }

  // Toggle the flag during the animation
  disableIn = true;
  setTimeout(function(){
    disableIn = false;
  },animationDelayIn);
});

$(".logo").mouseleave(function(){

  currentlyIn = false;

  if(!disableOut){
    //otherAnimation
  }

  // Toggle the flag during the animation
  disableOut = true;
  setTimeout(function(){
    disableOut = false;
    if(!currentlyIn){
      $(".logo").trigger("mouseleave");  // If the mouse is out, yeah, do the out animation now.
    }
  },animationDelayOut);
});
```

Disclaimer: It a good starter... It needs to be tested with your animation. ;)